# Mocking a dependent service to a controller unit test in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have a problem when unit testing an Ionic app. I have seen similar questions, but none solved my problem.

Basically, this is my **controller.js**

```
angular.module('starter.controllers')
.controller('myController', function($scope, myService) {

    $scope.test = function() {
        return myService.getTestVariable();
    };

});
```

and this is my **service.js**

```
angular.module('starter.services')
.factory('myService', function() {

    var self = this;
    self.testVariable = true;

    return {
        getTestVariable : function() {
            return self.testVariable;
        }
    };
});
```

Modules are created in a **app.js** file:

```
angular.module('starter', ['starter.controllers', 'starter.services']);           
angular.module('starter.services', []);
angular.module('starter.controllers', []);
```

Now, I want to test the controller and use a mock versione of the service, so I set up the test like this:

```
describe('Controller: myController', function() {
    var scope, controller, serviceMock;

    beforeEach(function() {
        module('starter');
    });

    beforeEach(function () {
        serviceMock= {
            getTestVariable : function() {return true;}
        };

        module(function ($provide) {
            $provide.value('myService', serviceMock);
        });
    });

    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        controller = $controller('myController', {
            $scope: scope
        });
    }));

    it('should work as expected', function(){
        spyOn(serviceMock, 'getTestVariable').and.callThrough();
        scope.test();
        expect(serviceMock.getTestVariable).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

However, when I try to run the test, it prints an error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'myService.getTestVariable()')
    at <dir>/controller.js:5
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem in the code, just do module initialisation `angular.module('starter.services', []); angular.module('starter.controllers', []);` before its used.

See the below example. same code you provided works perfectly.

```js
angular.module('starter.controllers', []);
angular.module('starter.controllers')
  .controller('myController', function($scope, myService) {

    $scope.test = function() {
      return myService.getTestVariable();
    };

  });

angular.module('starter.services', []);
angular.module('starter.services')
  .factory('myService', function() {

    var self = this;
    self.testVariable = true;

    return {
      getTestVariable: function() {
        return self.testVariable;
      }
    };
  });

angular.module('starter', ['starter.controllers', 'starter.services']);

describe('Controller: myController', function() {
  var scope, controller, serviceMock;

  beforeEach(function() {
    module('starter');
  });

  beforeEach(function() {
    serviceMock = {
      getTestVariable: function() {
        return true;
      }
    };

    module(function($provide) {
      $provide.value('myService', serviceMock);
    });
  });

  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    controller = $controller('myController', {
      $scope: scope
    });
  }));

  it('should work as expected', function() {
    spyOn(serviceMock, 'getTestVariable').and.callThrough();
    scope.test();
    expect(serviceMock.getTestVariable).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.2.1/jasmine.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.2.1/jasmine.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.2.1/jasmine-html.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.2.1/boot.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular-mocks.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
```